# Is there any discrepencies in my code as I was encounting an error when I clicked on the image to add

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-intent

Here's the code of database and the activity to add images in the database. The name of the database and the activity is database and camera_activity respectively.

Database-:

```
package com.database.log_on;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String data = "imagedata.db";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.database.log_on/databases/";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public database(Context context){
super(context, data, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void OpenDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(data).getPath();
    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public void CloseDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase != null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}
public long ImageInsert(int id, byte[] image) {
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put("ID", id);
    content.put("IMAGE", image);
    OpenDatabase();
    long returnValue = mDatabase.insert("GALLERYPIC", null, content);
    CloseDatabase();
    return returnValue;
}
```

}

In the activity I have used the above database to store image and the database gets stored in the phone itself
Activity-:

```
    package com.database.log_on;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    import static android.media.MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA;

    public class cameraactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button submit,picture,showit;
        private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
        ImageView img_view;
        database dbf;
        private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cameraactivity);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        picture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.images);
        img_view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_camera);
        showit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
        dbf=new database(cameraactivity.this);



        File database1 = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(database.data);
        if(false == database1.exists()){
            dbf.getReadableDatabase();
            if(copyDatabase(this)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Database copied successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
});
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           int id=Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("idl"));
            try {
                long result = dbf.ImageInsert(id,imageViewToByte(img_view));
                if (result > 0)
                    Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Please Check code...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
}
    public byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            img_view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(cameraactivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private void showPictureDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {"Select photo from gallery", "Capture photo from camera"};
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }
    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }
    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(database.data);
            String outFileName = database.DBLOCATION + database.data;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.w("signup","DB copied");
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

All the functions and the variables are well defined and the error I get is 
"Failed to allocate a 51916812-byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 44MB until OOM".

Comment: It looks like you don't have enough space

Answer (score 0):

With an image whose size is 49M (51916812 bytes) you will encounter issues even if you do manage to store the image in the database. A **CursorWindow** has a limitation of 2M so you would not be able to retrieve the image using the standard **SQLiteDatabase** class.

- Even at 0.5M you would possible find storing images in the database problematic. Images of up to 100k (perhaps more) can effectively and efficiently be stored, based upon the findings from  [SQLite - 35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)

As such you should not store the image but save the image in a suitable location as a file and store the path to the image in the database.

However, your current issue is that the app at the time of the failure only has 16M of free memory. I'd suggest reading [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java) and or doing a search say for example on *android image out of memory*